# Does Paranoia 2017 have a Perversity Point system?

Tags: paranoia-2017

Does the 2017 version of Paranoia include an equivalent of the old perversity points system, points handed out to reward great role playing or suitably loyal behaviour, which could be spent to make a task easier, or make someone else's task harder?

If not could they be easily worked into the system? I know it's a D6 system.

Reading online I have seen a-lot of explanation about the new character generation, the combat cards etc but nowhere have I seen any mention of perversity points or an equivalent. I know that there are now experience points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no Perversity Points in Paranoia 2017. However, there are two new things: Number One Troubleshooter and XP Points.

The Number One Troubleshooter is a card—best displayed in a little plastic stand—that can be awarded to the Troubleshooter who best acts in accordance with The Computer's wishes. As soon as another Troubleshooter does something cool, though, you're supposed to immediately move the title to them.

> Mechanically, it does nothing. Fictionally, though, other citizens might notice and treat the character in a special way. It's something for the Troubleshooters to compete for.

In the new Paranoia, Alpha Complex is entirely gamified. XP Points can be awarded at The Computer's whim, but the easiest way for the Troubleshooters to earn XP Points is through Achievements, which are provided along with the mission.  The mission itself also has a juicy XP Points reward, but this is often reduced based on any mishaps that might occur during the mission. Troubleshooters can spend XP Points anytime to get useful rewards from The Computer, such as weapons, armor, drugs, and improved stats.

To some extent, you can also reward clever players with Equipment cards.

Comment: Ok reading what I have online I may still include perversity points in the game myself, think it should be fairly straightforward to treat each point as an automatic success roll, or if played by other players treat it as a -ve stat (rtolls of 1-4 result in a success being cancelled out) have ordered it online so will see how it all works. I always like to reward funny or clever moments without something as extreme as xp. plus its paranoia, what are the players going to do, argue the rules with me :) "Knowing the rules is a traitorous act, traitors will be executed"  :)

Comment: Just bought the new version, the new rules for Xp Points means they can be spent immediatly, not just after debrief so these will work really well in place of perversity points :)

Comment: @RichardC That's a good point I forgot to mention in my answer. Updated.

Comment: Just ran my first game went really well. Handing out 5-10 XP points as a reward for calling out treasonous behavior real or otherwise, throwing each other under the bus etc worked really well. I also added an extra dynamic allowing players to spend XP to make things harder for another player to do. For 100 xp points they could make a task I extra result harder. I kept track of who spent xp this way in game so they didn’t have to make it obvious on there sheet.